# HOW to encrypt by a subkey(multiple subkey(e)) in GPG(GnuPG)

Tags: gnupg

HOW to encrypt by a subkey(multiple subkey(e)) in GPG(GnuPG)

```
pub   rsa4096/22E49AB870AD169A 2017-03-09 [SC]
uid                 [ultimate] Jack Wonda <wangjievibeke@foxmail.com>
uid                 [ultimate] 王杰 <jack20130107@qq.com>
sub   rsa4096/D39A707D61F13A26 2017-03-09 [E] [expires: 2020-04-25]
sub   rsa4096/11FAB3E82F75B202 2017-04-24 [S] [expires: 2019-04-24]
sub   rsa4096/B305BA41FD1F7793 2017-04-26 [E] [expires: 2019-04-26]
```

I have two subkeys for encryption, but for now I can only use the last subkey(B305BA41FD1F7793).

For instance:

```
gpg2 -r D39A707D61F13A26 -e doc
File 'doc.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) y
gpg2 -d doc.gpg
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID B305BA41FD1F7793, created 2017-04-26
      "Jack Wonda <wangjievibeke@foxmail.com>"
123456
```

Even I specify the first subkey, it will still go to the last one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can force gpg to use a specific key by appending an exclamation point to its id. In your case :

```
gpg2 -r 0xD39A707D61F13A26! -e doc
```

You can even ask gpg to encrypt with **both** keys (so you can decrypt with either one of the associated public keys) :

```
gpg2 -r 0xD39A707D61F13A26! -r 0xB305BA41FD1F7793! -e doc
```

According to the manpage installed on my Arch system (strangely, I can't find the same version elsewhere with the same information) :

> HOW TO SPECIFY A USER ID
>
> There are different ways to specify a user ID to GnuPG.  Some  of  them
>   are  only  valid  for  gpg others are only good for gpgsm.  Here is the
>   entire list of ways to specify a key:
>
> ```
> By key Id.
>           This format is deduced from the length of  the  string  and  its
>           content or 0x prefix. The key Id of an X.509 certificate are the
>           low 64 bits of its SHA-1 fingerprint.  The use  of  key  Ids  is
>           just  a  shortcut,  for all automated processing the fingerprint
>           should be used.
>
>           When using gpg an exclamation mark (!) may be appended to  force
>           using  the specified primary or secondary key and not to try and
>           calculate which primary or secondary key to use.
>
>           The last four lines of the example give the key ID in their long
>           form as internally used by the OpenPGP protocol. You can see the
>           long key ID using the option --with-colons.
> ```